# LTE: Lost/Stolen Phone in another country, didn't receive text/data/voicemails after new SIM?

Tags: sim-card, 4g, gsm

I had an unfortunate situation occur to me where my phone was pick pocketed out of my pocket while on Vacation out of the country. We decided to not cancel the phone line because doing so would disable the find my phone features on the phone. I would have to rely on wifi connection if cellular data was shut off. Anyway, I monitored the phone and my stolen phone number for a week and a half before I was like this phone will never be turned on (essentially radio silence since stolen). I had enough and then I just informed my carrier to blacklist the phone and give me a new SIM card. I was expecting that once I popped in the new SIM card into my old Smart phone I would start receiving all the missed calls and texts on my phone, but none came through. In fact I only received ones that appeared to happen today.

I was wondering what happened. I talked to my family and friends and they all said they were calling/messaging/etc my phone number since it was stolen in order to see if they would get a response. The phone was stolen in Mexico and I was using At&t's international roaming because it was free there. If anyone wanted to get in touch with me in Mexico, I know they were able to because I was communicating with them free of charge out of Mexico no problem with everything as if it was that I was in the states. In any case, is there an explanation what happened here?

Stolen phone: 
Galaxy S7 
At&T Mexican Free Roaming
Stolen in Mexico

~ 1.5 weeks elasped

New Phone:
Galaxy S5
Started up in USA with my same number
At&T USA service

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: No answers? Is the question unclear or in the wrong spot?

Comment: My sincerest sympathies for the unfortunate event. This site is about Android-related stuff. Your SIM and your GSM operator is not necessarily related to Android. Therefore, even though I think your question is OK to stay here, you might not be able to receive a good answer in any time soon.

Comment: Thank you for your concern. It has been a few months since and it has been a process securing my data and protecting my identity. It seems that nothing bad has come as a result of it but I certainly lost all those messages (verified by my friends and family members). I believe that @abochur's answer hit the mark. Thank you ! I appreciate your sympathies!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are that no messages were sent to you in the last 72 hours, and they were deleted. At&t will only try delivering the texts for 72 hours and then they delete them from the servers

> All the messages sent are retried for up to 72 hours and any
>   undelivered messages get deleted after that 
>   [Source](https://developer.att.com/sms/docs)

As for missed calls, you will never receive missed call notification for calls that were made while your phone is off, unless a voicemail was left.

I'm not sure why no voicemails came in. It's possible that it's similar to what I wrote about sms's above, that they get deleted after 72 hours.

Also possible that your phones data was turned off, and therefore you did not see it in Google's device manager. But all texts and calls came to that phone.

Comment: Why do they call it retry period? To me that sounds like it will retry every 72 hours.

Comment: Retried for UP TO 72 hours. How do you explain "any undelivered messages get deleted after that"? Isnt "that"=72h?

Comment: I just didn't want to believe it...thanks though for helping me face the music. That confirm is as good as it gets. I marked your answer as the best answer. Thanks for your feedback.